# What are the patterns/idioms for introducing [boolean] configuration flags/parameters in a Java application?

Tags: java, configuration, boolean, configuration-files

I have a Java application (an interpreter written in antlr4 to be precise) with numerous options in the code I would like to be [power] user configurable.  Something like a config.properties file.  Most of them are Boolean flags, if set, do this, else do that.

Currently, I have one class per flag, and the classes are scattered through-out the code, mostly in the same package where the implementation needs it.  And, you can say:

```
import  my.package.DoThis;

   if (DoThis.isSet()) {
       doThis();
   } else {
       doThat();
   }
```

where the code for DoThis is something like

```
package my.package;

public class DoThis {

  private static Boolean doThis = true; // the default
  public static Boolean isSet() { return doThis; }
  public static void set() { doThis = true; }
  public static void clear() { doThis = false; }
}
```

And, there is a centralized part of the code that main calls, that initializes these options.

```
public void setup() {
   DoThis.set();
   DoAnother.clear();
   if (cmd.option.debug()) { DoThird.set(); } else { DoThird.clear(): }
}
```

But, as I said, I'd like to clean the code up and use a configuration file that I can keep in the resources or a power user can override. A properties file or maybe a json file would seem like the right user interface.

However, properties read strings, do I check for yes/no, true/false? to set the flag.  Or is there something better to do?

Should I also make all the options part of one class and perhaps store them in a map?  What will make adding configuration options easiest?

Most importantly, I'd like to follow some form of Java best practices for doing so.  I don't want to be that person who can write FORTRAN in any language.  I want the code to look like what other Java programmers would naturally write.  I'm pretty certain what I have now is not it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not aware of a universally-accepted "best" approach for this. My preference would be *not* to have a separate class per flag, but rather to rather to centralise all the flags within a single class called, say, `Config`. It's public API might be something like the following (assuming the flags are called `x`, `y` and `z`):

```
public class Config {
  private boolean x;
  private boolean y;
  private boolean z;
  void setX(boolean value) { x = value; }
  boolean getX() { return x; }
  void setY(boolean value) { y = value; }
  boolean getY() { return y; }
  void setZ(boolean value) { z = value; }
  boolean getZ() { return z; }
}
```

If you don't want to have to pass an instance of `Config` as a parameter to lots of different operations/constructors in your application, then you could create a singleton instance of `Config`.

I don't think my suggestion above would be too controversial among programmers. What is more likely to attract controversy is opinions about the "best" way to initialise the `Config` object. Some people might suggest that the Spring Framework should be used to inject values obtained from an XML file. Some other people might suggest that your `setup()` operation should read values from a configuration file in whatever happens to be your favourite syntax (properties, JSON, XML or whatever) and possibly allowing command-line options to override values specified in the configuration file

Comment: Thanks, the single class is what I was leaning toward also.  I can "easily" make an Emacs macro that merges/converts the separate classes I have now into a format like you have suggested.

Any reason to have explicit variables rather than a "map" as the implementation.  If I use a map, it is easy to use existing serialization/deserialization code to initialize it.

Comment: The combination of a private variable plus public get and set operations to access it is called a *property* in Java terminology and is a commonly used idiom, so this will feel familiar to other programmers. Aside from that, a call to `boolean getX()` will execute in just a few clock cycles, while a call to `bool get(String name)` will require many more clock cycles to execute if the implementation has to lookup a map and possibly convert the returned value to a boolean. So if configuration values will be queried frequently & performance is important, then the property-based approach is good.

Comment: Another potential benefit of using the property-based approach is that this is what the Spring Framework works with, but that is only relevant if you are thinking of using Spring. I have never used Java-based serialization/deserialization, so I don't whether this is easier or more difficult to do with the property-based approach than with a map-based approach.

Comment: Interesting points.  The Apache "Properties" class reads a file and makes a map string->string.  We have at least one other piece of code that uses it, to read in settings for the "environment variables".  So, I'm tempted to follow it's pattern and having both a map and a variable seems like overkill, especially given that after reading in the map, one would need to populate the variables, most of which are never actually used except in rare sections of the code, so I would be paying for the map lookup to populate the variable in cases where the code never uses it.

Comment: I suppose I could make variables to memoize the value if it is ever retrieved.  I will consider that if I find performance for certain variables becoming an issue.  At the moment, getting working code that implements the correct semantics (and is maintainable) is more important than tweaking performance.

Comment: But yes, I am burying the get(string name) and set(string name) calls inside getX, setX calls for each property.  So, moving from a map to a specific variable isn't a big deal, it doesn't impact the caller/users of the properties, just how I fill their value in.  So, this piece of advice was particularly apt (and I am following it).